# I am trying to downgrade my HP envy 8 1414 from Windows 8 to Windows 7 and need the sata controller driver

Tags: windows-7, drivers, downgrade

I have downloaded several drivers and extracted the files, but none seem to be working for me. I have seen a couple of posts about this, but I keep running into the wall. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Unless you are trying to do a RAID you don't need drivers to install `Windows 7` on your desktop. Furthermore there is nothing that would stop http://ftp.hp.com/pub/softpaq/sp58501-59000/sp58709.exe from installing on Windows 7 x64. Since HP offers no 32-bit drivers a 32-bit installation of `Windows` cannot be used.

Comment: So Windows 7 32 bit cannot be installed on this pc is what your saying.

Comment: Tried Win 7 64 bit and the installation still stops and says that a required cd/dvd drive device driver is missing.

Comment: That is exactly what I am saying.  Does it tell you what driver is missing exactly?  You shouldn't have to provide a RAID driver is your not using a RAID.

Comment: Here is the error message... A required CD/DVD drive device driver is missing. If you have a driver floppy disk, CD, DVD, or USB falsh drive, please insert it now.  Note:If the Windows installation media is in the CD/DVD drive, you can safely remove it for this step.

Comment: Are you sure your not trying to install Windows with RAID enabled by chance?

Comment: Whoops... Just checked Storage options and SATA Emulation is set to RAID

Comment: Changed it to AHCI and am now in the process of downgrading. Thanks Ramhound!

Comment: If you can generate and answer I will upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

Booted in to Bios and under Storage Options, changed it from SATA to AHCI, booted with Windows 7 64bit cd and deleted the partitions, formatted the drive and installed Windows 7.